# Idiomatic CSV export in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have an index view of `submissions` and in the view I have `@submissions` the controller looks like this:

#### Submissions Controller

```rb
def index 
  @submissions = Submission.submissions_for(user: current_user)
end
```

From the view I want to essentially click a button and pass in that list of `submissions`

I've thought of adding a new route like so:

```rb
<%= link_to "Export", export_submissions_path(submissions: @submissions) %>
```

But that doesn't feel quite right because I need to stay on the index page. So when the user clicks the `export` button they stay on the `index` page but a CSV of the current data gets created. So, this questions is "how to create a CSV" it's more how do I stay on the index page and send a request to the server to send a CSV?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can deliver different formats of a view from a single controller action.

```
class SubmissionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @submissions = Submission.submissions_for(user: current_user)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @submissions.to_csv, filename: "users-#{Date.today}.csv" }
  end
end
```

Then if you do the request with `.csv` it will deliver the csv instead of the view.

To get the right url use the url_helper as follows:

```
link_to 'CSV Export', submissions_path(format: :csv)
```